# What is the range of integral for this? ( integration by substitution)

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Say the area, $D_t$ be enclosed by the line $x+y\geq t$, $x+y\leq 2t$, $x-y\geq t$ and $x-y\leq 2t$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ plane. (Here $ t >0$)
Find $f(t) =\int\int_{D_t} \vert x \vert +\vert y \vert  dA$.

I would say the area $D(x,y)$ be area enclosed by  $x+y\geq t$, $x+y\leq 2t$ and axes. Both $D_t$ and function $g(x,y) = \vert x \vert + \vert y \vert $ are symmetric for the y-axis, So I got the $f(t) = 2\int\int_{D(x,y)} (x + y) dA$

Next I put $u=x+y, v=x-y$. Hence $f(t) = \int\int_{D(u,v)} u dudv$. But The real problem of mine is determining range of the integral.

In my thought, $D(u,v) = \{(u,v)\vert t\leq u \leq 2t, -u \leq v \leq u\}$ Considering the boundary points $\{(t,0), (0,t), (2t,0), (0,2t) \}$ of $D(x,y)$. Therefore my answer is $f(t) = \int_{t}^{2t}\int_{-u}^{u} u dv du = \frac{14t^3}{3}$. But the answer sheet made by lecture claimed $f(t) = \int_{t}^{2t}\int_{t}^{u} u dv du = \frac{5t^3}{6} $. He did same method comparing with mine by putting $u=x+y, v=x-y$. I can't find which point did I miss. Please help me to find my errors.

Answer (score 1):

- $f(t)$ is not $2\iint_{D(x,y)} (x + y) dxdy.$ It is $2\iint_{D(x,y)\cap[y\ge0]} (x + y) dxdy.$
- This factor $2$ is compensated by the Jacobian of the change of variable, so $f(t)=\iint_{E(u,v)}u dudv,$ where $E(u,v)$ is the image of $D(x,y)\cap[y\ge0]$ by this change.
- $E(u,v)=\{(u,v)\mid t\le u\le2t,t\le v\le2t,\frac{u-v}2\ge0\}=\{(u,v)\mid t\le u\le2t,t\le v\le u\}.$